# "failed to create task or type testng" error is getting when selenium webdriver code running in command prompt

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ant

When i am executing build.xml in cmd then it is showing error like "failed to create task or type testng".

I have searched all the StackOverflow answers about my issue but I am unable to rectify. below is my build.xml code.

```
<target name="run" depends="compile">
<testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="suite">
<xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="TestNG.xml"/>
</testng>
</target>
```

and below line is for taskdef

```
<taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${lib}/testng-6.9.9.jar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been rectified by me. added below lines to the existing one.

```
<taskdef name="testng" classpath="${test.classpath}"
    classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />
        <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${lib}/testng-6.9.9.jar"/>
```